# How to convert String to int [] array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Am looking for the code which need to convert string to int array so far what i done is :

```
string text = "[1,2]";
int[] ia = text.Split(';').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```

But am getting number format exception how to get rid of this here is the string "[1,2]" need to convert into [1,2] how can i achieve this it may be dumb question but need to solve this.

Comment: Why do you expect Split(";") to work on "[1,2]"? Also, you'll have to remove the leading [ and ending ] first.

Comment: as a new to c# how can i achieve this

Comment: Yeah. Common sense obviously got missing. On top, he example is not according to site rules as it contains a ton of irrelevant code and does not even compile. Venkat, please cut the crap out and make the smallest example possible. Which means: Define a string with input, write convert logic, have int array as output - the rest IS IRRELEVANT FOR THE QUESTION. And try a minute debugging before dumping the work on other people - particularly if you read Martheen's comment we really get the idea you never learned programming and just copy/paste.

Comment: F1 on Split, read the documentation first

Comment: @TomTom - Go easy on him. He's new. I think you've got a valid point, but the number of times I've ask people to post more code because they think they've posted enough versus times I've asked people to cut down code is about 20 to 1.

Comment: @venkatraman - The point about SO is to create a repository of good quality questions and answers for the community at large. It's not specifically about giving the asker and answer. So when you get feedback in comments it's about improving the quality of the question (or answer). Just take it as such.

Comment: @venkatraman - I've edited your question to show you want you probably should have written. Feel free to rollback or edit, but I thought this might give you a better idea.

Comment: I you guys does not want to share the solution please don't discourage i thought stack overflow is the place where beginners could learn

Comment: @venkatraman SO is [not a place for learning basic programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19590/is-stack-overflow-an-effective-platform-for-studying-programming). Pressing F1 on Visual Studio would tell you everything you need in this question. If MSDN can't answer you, and there's nothing on Google, then and only then you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a piece of cake using JsonConvert,

```
 int[] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Trim the string's '[' and ']' and split by ',' to get it as array.
Then convert it to int array using 'Array.ConvertAll' method.

```
string s = "[1,2]";
string[] s1 = s.Trim('[', ']').Split(',');
int[] myArr = Array.ConvertAll(s1, n => int.Parse(n));
```

Comment: Tips, you can replace the lambda expression with just int.Parse, since it's exactly the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the braces `[]` with empty string and then apply `Split` function.

```
objModellead.ServiceCatalogID
     .Replace("[","")
     .Replace("]","")
     .Split(';')
     .Select(int.Parse)
     .ToArray()
```